Effects Contrast Matrix for Interaction with Multiple Grand Means
I want to include an interaction between two factors: area and house_type, in my GAM (MGCV), I hope to make a sum-to-zero contrast encoding.
But, I do not want each combination of the factors to be compared to the grand mean across all levels. I want a grand mean for each level of area. So then the house_types within each area are compared to the grand mean for that area.
Here's what I've tried
Taking the contrast matrix for house_type'. There are 7 types: it is a 7*6 matrix.  [house_type` contrast matrix](https://i.sstatic.net/2ZliQWM6.png)
For 6 levels of area I created a matrix made up of the house_type contrast matrices on the diagonal and null matrices of the same size on the off diagonals. This is 42*36.
The first two submatrices are shown here: First two submatrices of the contrast matrix of the interaction term
Queries

Is there a better way to do this?
Running a simple linear regression with the interaction term, I get NA coefficients - why is this?
Is there an overall intercept in this model or is it one intercept for each level of area representing the grand mean?

Thank you

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.
